My database connection passes the connection test but dosent actually connect
So I'm making a webapp using IntelliJ and run it with the jar file. When i run it on localhost it works perfectly but as soon as i run it on the server it just says "The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request". I think its because the server is not able to connect to the database but i have tried literally everything and still cant seem to be able to solve this issue. I have tried putting print statements to check but nothing works. the one on localhost works but i think its just not bale to connect to the server what do i do?
